# Hive query: grouping data statewise and getting count of a decade

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

Im a Hive newbie, this looks like a tricky query for me. Any help will be greatly appreciated. We are having accident data statewise, we have statistics of accidents month wise and yearwise.

How can we group the data statewise, sum up all the months accident numbers and get a sum total of 12 years. Output should be State name, Acciden Type:. Accident Types are "Road Accidents", "Rail-Road Accidents", "Other Railway Accidents"

We created the following table and [data can be found here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kwz4EiXK9LK3qN-zxyU5Cm32rvequYKA97JqaA7BGeY/pub)

```
create table accidents_data(STATE string,Year string,AcciddentType string,JANUARY int,FEBRUARY int,MARCH int ,APRIL int,MAY int,JUNE int,JULY int,AUGUST int,SEPTEMBER int,OCTOBER int,NOVEMBER int,DECEMBER int)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I saw in  the data, you missed the last column "TOTAL" in Hive schema. IF that column is present then following query will do your work.

```
select STATE, AcciddentType, sum(TOTAL) as GrandTotal
where AcciddentType!='Total'
group by STATE, AcciddentType;
```

Update:
If you don't have the last column "TOTAL" in Hive schema then following query will work:

```
select STATE, AcciddentType, (
sum(JANUARY) +
sum(FEBRUARY) +
sum(MARCH) +
sum(APRIL) +
sum(MAY) +
sum(JUNE) +
sum(JULY) +
sum(AUGUST) +
sum(SEPTEMBER) +
sum(OCTOBER) +
sum(NOVEMBER) +
sum(DECEMBER)
) as GrandTotal
where AcciddentType!='Total'
group by STATE, AcciddentType;
```

Comment: Assume Total column is not there, What would be the likely query.